# How would a gravity-based AoE Flight attack be resisted?

Tags: character-creation, powers, mutants-and-masterminds-3e, mutants-and-masterminds

I'm trying to build a power that changes which way is "down" in a certain volume. I'm planning to use the Flight effect, with Burst Area and Attack modifiers. As I understand it, unwilling targets would get a Dodge resistance check for half-effect, and then another resistance check to avoid all effect.

I'm not sure what *kind* of check that would be, or how often targets would make it (only once? once per round?). I feel like acrobatics or athletics would make sense for grabbing on to something or getting out of the affected area. Can skills be used for resistance checks? And if so, would it warrant the use of the "alternate resistance" extra?

Answer (score 2):

Like any **Area** attack, it allows a Dodge resistance to mitigate the effect. Which you noted in the question.

Most anti-gravity effects are Move Object (as [Sean Duggan noted](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/165177/42345)), which can be resisted with Strength or Dodge (per Grab attacks in the **Action & Adventure** Chapter).

For a Flight effect, you'll need to choose an appropriate resistance. If the targets simply grab stationary objects, or jump out of the area, then a Dodge resistance check would be fitting. If the targets will themselves to ignore the power than a Will resistance check would be most appropriate. If you wanted to make it Athletics to resist then you can do that but you should append the Alternate Resistance modifier since skills aren't normally used to resist power effects; also keep in mind that skills have a much higher Power Limit than resistances have (10 + PL versus PL), making it trivial for characters with a high skill bonus to ignore the power effect.

*Aside:* If you're using Flight then make sure you add the Levitation modifier.

Answer (score 0):

The Gravity section of Green Ronin's *Power Profiles* suggests an Area **Move Object** limited to moving things upwards:

> The reverse of the Gravity Field power (previously), in a
>   Null-G Field, if the effect rank equals or exceeds a subject’s
>   weight rank, the subject floats, weightless, inside the field.
>   This leaves subjects without other movement capabilities
>   effectively immobilized.
>   **Null-G Field**: Burst Area Move Object, Limited to Lifting
>   Upwards • 2 points per rank

If you're intending to be able to vary which direction gravity is, I'd say it's more of a 1 PP Quirk that everything being moved has to go in one cardinal direction. Otherwise, it's basically an area Grab attack followed by moving those affected. Alternately, you might use one of the alternate Knockback rules in the Strength section:

> ... For attacks that just fling targets away, you can use the
>   Move Object effect, modified by the target’s weight
>   rank, with effect rank minus weight rank equalling
>   the distance rank the target is thrown. The target gets
>   a Strength check against the Move Object rank +10
>   to avoid being thrown. Optionally, you can base the
>   distance on the difference between a failed Strength
>   check and the Difficulty Class (effect rank + 10), with a
>   maximum distance of (effect rank – weight rank), for a
>   system similar to the knockback caused by damage described in the *Gamemaster’s Guide*.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my other answer didn't strictly answer your question of what resistance would be used for the power you stated, rather giving a "correct" way to do the power effect.

Yes, a non-Perception range attack gives a Dodge check for half effect (for no effect in some cases such as sensory effects or dropped objects). Perception-range effects don't offer that Dodge check, and the Gravity Power Profiles suggests that a GM might allow a +1 Extra to remove the Dodge check for powers where it makes sense (for a Ranged power, this would work much like making it a Perception range power. For a Close attack, it would just remove the Dodge attack while keeping the range close). The initial Dodge check is only for the initial attack. Subsequently, they would be saving against the ongoing effect. The Attack extra does not define how this works, but most ongoing effects operate on a round-by-round basis, with the target rolling to resist at the end of their turn after the first check.

And yes, skills can be used for Alternate Resistance checks, as long as the GM is on-board. They occupy an odd middle ground where the bonus can be higher than PL, making resistance almost effortless, but depending on how common or uncommon the skill is, the target might have only an ability bonus if they have no ranks. My general policy as a GM is that, much like any Skill check, the listed skill is a suggestion, and a player who can justify using a similar skill should be allowed to. A canonical case is [Snare](https://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/sample-powers/snare/), which offers different resistance methods for escaping it after the initial attack, and at that offers more than one venue of getting out of it.